# Get-AzRoleAssignment: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown

Tags: azure-powershell, lighthouse

We have lighthouse configured and I am trying to extract azure aks RBAC permissions information for a managing subscription from a managed tenant:
Get-AzRoleAssignment -scope "/subscriptions/0000000-0000-0000-00000000000000/resourcegroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/testakscluster

Can we extract role assignments for a managing tenant's subscription while logged in a managed tenant cloud shell?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Get-AzRoleAssignment` command, it will call the Azure AD Graph - [`getObjectsByObjectIds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getObjectsByObjectIds) meanwhile to validate the objects in Azure AD.

To solve the  issue, make sure your user account logged in the cloud shell has permission to call the API, if your user account type is `member`, it will has the permission by default. So I suppose your user account is a `guest`, if so, there are two ways.

1.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `User settings` -> click `Manage external collaboration settings` -> select the first option like below.

[image]

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> search for `Directory readers` -> click it -> `Add assignments` -> add your user account as a `Directory readers` role.

[image]

Just select any of the options above, then the command will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this thread after some searching: I had the same issue with this call across multiple versions of the AZ.Resources module: 2.5.0, 4.1.0 an 5.6.0. All my rights where setup correctly, both for an SPN and a user, both got the same error.

Changing the call to use the Azure CLI and that just works .

`az role assignment list -g [resource group name]`